# Axis of symmetry parallel to the y-axis and passes through the points (1, 1), (2, 2) and (-1, 5)

Tags: trigonometry

For this problem, we are given a hint that we should apply the general form of the equation which is:

$$x^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$ or $$y^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$

how should I solve this one? is this simply substituting or not?

Thank you very much.

Comment: First, use the criterion regarding its axis of symmetry to know which form it is in. The parabolas with the $x^2$ term have the axis of symmetry in one direction; the parabolas with the $y^2$ term have the axis of symmetry in another direction. Then it is indeed just substitution. Plug in the three points to find $D, E, $ and $F$. Three equations, three unknowns.

Comment: may I ask how can I plug in those points in the formula?

Comment: The point $(-1,5)$ being on the parabola means that you can plug in $x=-1$ and $y=5$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Take the parabola as $y=ax^2+bx+c$, stisfy it with points $(1,1), (2,2), (-1,5)$ to get $a,b,c$ from three equations.